# Difference between a virtual function and a pure virtual function

Tags: c++, function, pure-virtual

What is the difference between a pure virtual function and a virtual function?

I know "Pure Virtual Function is a Virtual function with no body", but what does this mean and what is actually done by the line below:

```
virtual void virtualfunctioname() = 0
```

Comment: "a Virtual function with no body" > that's incorrect. they can very much have bodies.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

A virtual function makes its class a *polymorphic base class*. Derived classes can override virtual functions. Virtual functions called through base class pointers/references will be resolved at run-time. That is, the *dynamic type* of the object is used instead of its *static type*:

```
 Derived d;
 Base& rb = d;
 // if Base::f() is virtual and Derived overrides it, Derived::f() will be called
 rb.f();
```

A pure virtual function is a virtual function whose declaration ends in `=0`:

```
class Base {
  // ...
  virtual void f() = 0;
  // ...
```

A pure virtual function implicitly makes the class it is defined for *abstract* (unlike in Java where you have a keyword to explicitly declare the class abstract). Abstract classes cannot be instantiated. Derived classes need to override/implement all inherited pure virtual functions. If they do not, they too will become abstract.

An interesting 'feature' of C++ is that a class can define a pure virtual function that has an implementation. 
([What that's good for is debatable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2609299/140719).)

---

Note that C++11 brought a new use for the `delete` and `default` keywords which looks similar to the syntax of pure virtual functions:

```
my_class(my_class const &) = delete;
my_class& operator=(const my_class&) = default;
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5513881) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13576055) for more info on this use of `delete` and `default`.

Comment: Oh, so a pure virtual function is almost the same thing as a method in Java/C# interfaces.  Neat.

Comment: @Nick: Indeed. Only that C++ gives you more freedom about it. (You can implement pure virtual functions in C++ and you can mix pure, non-pure, and non-virtual functions in the same class. (Usually it's a good idea to not to do that, but if you need it, you can.)

Comment: @Sbi I think the surmising point of "use =0 for pure virtual functions" is worth leaving in. Perhaps even just adding to the end "In short, if you want pure virtual function, use `=0`"

Comment: hehe interesting "feature"  ...or "bug" ? after all it can be one or the other its interchangeable

Comment: @Xsmael: Stroustrup declares it a feature that you can do this with any pure virtual function. (It is _necessary_ for pure virtual dtors, and Stroustrup has said on numerous occasions that he isn't fond of syntactical restrictions.) And, no, a function can be both pure virtual _and_ implemented. I'll add a link to a question where this is debated.

Answer (score 43):

For a virtual function you need to provide implementation in the base class. However derived class can override this implementation with its own implementation. Normally , for pure virtual functions implementation is not provided. You can make a function pure virtual with `=0` at the end of function declaration. Also, a class containing a pure virtual function is abstract i.e. you can not create a object of this class.

Answer (score 26):

A pure virtual function is usually not (but can be) implemented in a base class and must be implemented in a leaf subclass.

You denote that fact by appending the "= 0" to the declaration, like this:

```
class AbstractBase
{
    virtual void PureVirtualFunction() = 0;
}
```

Then you cannot declare and instantiate a subclass without it implementing the pure virtual function:

```
class Derived : public AbstractBase
{
    virtual void PureVirtualFunction() override { }
}
```

By adding the `override` keyword, the compiler will ensure that there is a base class virtual function with the same signature.

Comment: In C++, a pure virtual function can be implemented.

Comment: yes, and for the pure virtual destructor, it must be implemented.

Comment: @daramarak: pure virtual constructor ? in C++?

Comment: @Naveen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609299/2609404#2609404

Comment: @sbi: I read at is constructor instead of destructor. My mistake..

Comment: @Naveen: Min e, too. I read yours as "destructor"...

Answer (score 10):

You can actually [provide implementations of pure virtual functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609299/use-cases-of-pure-virtual-functions-with-body) in C++.  The only difference is all pure virtual functions must be implemented by derived classes before the class can be instantiated.