# How is "=default" different from "{}" for default constructor and destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-functions, default-constructor, deleted-functions

I originally posted this as a question only about destructors, but now I'm adding consideration of the default constructor.  Here's the original question:

> If I want to give my class a destructor that is virtual, but is
>   otherwise the same as what the compiler would generate, I can use `=default`:
>
> ```
> class Widget {
> public:
>    virtual ~Widget() = default;
> };
> ```
>
> But it seems that I can get the same effect with less typing using an
>   empty definition:
>
> ```
> class Widget {
> public:
>    virtual ~Widget() {}
> };
> ```
>
> Is there any way in which these two definitions behave differently?

Based on the replies posted for this question, the situation for the default constructor seems similar.  Given that there is almost no difference in meaning between "`=default`" and "`{}`" for destructors, is there similarly almost no difference in meaning between these options for default constructors?  That is, assuming I want to create a type where the objects of that type will be both created and destroyed, why would I want to say

```
Widget() = default;
```

instead of

```
Widget() {}
```

?

I apologize if extending this question after its original posting is violating some SO rules.  Posting an almost-identical question for default constructors struck me as the less desirable option.

Comment: Not that I know of, but `= default` is more explicit imo, and is consistent with the support for it with constructors.

Comment: A virtual destructor is never trivial.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828907/the-new-syntax-default-in-c11

Answer (score 154, accepted):

This is a completely different question when asking about constructors than destructors.

If your destructor is `virtual`, then the difference is negligible, [as Howard pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13576544/734069). However, if your destructor was *non-virtual*, it's a completely different story. The same is true of constructors.

Using `= default` syntax for special member functions (default constructor, copy/move constructors/assignment, destructors etc) means something very different from simply doing `{}`. With the latter, the function becomes "user-provided". And that changes everything.

This is a trivial class by C++11's definition:

```
struct Trivial
{
  int foo;
};
```

If you attempt to default construct one, the compiler will generate a default constructor automatically. Same goes for copy/movement and destructing. Because the user did not provide any of these member functions, the C++11 specification considers this a "trivial" class. It therefore legal to do this, like memcpy their contents around to initialize them and so forth.

This:

```
struct NotTrivial
{
  int foo;

  NotTrivial() {}
};
```

As the name suggests, this is no longer trivial. It has a default constructor that is user-provided. It doesn't matter if it's empty; as far as the rules of C++11 are concerned, this cannot be a trivial type.

This:

```
struct Trivial2
{
  int foo;

  Trivial2() = default;
};
```

Again as the name suggests, this is a trivial type. Why? Because you told the compiler to automatically generate the default constructor. The constructor is therefore not "user-provided." And therefore, the type counts as trivial, since it doesn't have a user-provided default constructor.

The `= default` syntax is mainly there for doing things like copy constructors/assignment, when you add member functions that prevent the creation of such functions. But it also triggers special behavior from the compiler, so it's useful in default constructors/destructors too.

Comment: So the key issue seems to be whether the resulting class is trivial, and underlying that issue is the difference between a special function being *user-declared* (which is the case for `=default` functions) and *user-provided* (which is the case for `{}`) functions. Both user-declared and user-provided functions can prevent the generation of other special member function (e.g., a user-declared destructor prevents generation of the move operations), but only a user-provided special function renders a class non-trivial.  Right?

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: That's the general idea, yes.

Comment: I'm choosing this as the accepted answer, only because it covers both constructors and (by reference to Howard's answer) destructors.

Comment: Seems to be a missing word in here "as far as the rules of C++11 are concerned, you the rights of a trivial type" I'd fix it but I'm not quuite 100% sure what was intended.

Comment: `= default` seems to be useful for forcing the compiler to generated a default constructor despite the presence of other constructors; the default constructor is not implicitly declared if any other user-declared constructors are provided.

Comment: There's another very important case, where there is a declaration in the class body and an out-of-body definition.  Both `= default` and `{}` at the definition are possible and the choice has different effects than it does at an inline definition.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe Does that mean (addressing your first comment) that a user-declared (i.e. `=default`) might prevent the automatic generation of a copy constructor, for instance?

Comment: Then what's the difference between declaring a destructor as `= default` and not declaring it at all?

Answer (score 54):

The important difference between

```
class B {
    public:
    B(){}
    int i;
    int j;
};
```

and

```
class B {
    public:
    B() = default;
    int i;
    int j;
};
```

is that default constructor defined with `B() = default;` is considered **not-user defined**. This means that in case of *value-initialization* as in

```
B* pb = new B();  // use of () triggers value-initialization
```

special kind of initialization that doesn't use a constructor at all will take place and for built-in types this will result in *zero-initialization*. In case of `B(){}` this won't take place. The C++ Standard n3337 **§** 8.5/7 says

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly
>   cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) **with a user-provided constructor**
>   (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the
>   initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
>   constructor);
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type
>   **without a user-provided constructor**, then the object is
>   zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor
>   is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
>
> — if T is an array type,
>   then each element is value-initialized; — otherwise, the object is
>   zero-initialized.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
    A(){}
    int i;
    int j;
};

class B {
    public:
    B() = default;
    int i;
    int j;
};

int main()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        A* pa = new A();
        B* pb = new B();
        std::cout << pa->i << "," << pa->j << std::endl;
        std::cout << pb->i << "," << pb->j << std::endl;
        delete pa;
        delete pb;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

possible result:

```
0,0
0,0
145084416,0
0,0
145084432,0
0,0
145084416,0
//...
```

http://ideone.com/k8mBrd

Comment: Then, why do "{}" and "= default" always initialize an std::string http://ideone.com/LMv5Uf ?

Comment: @nawfelbgh The default constructor A(){} calls default constructor for std::string as this is non-POD type. The default ctor of std::string [initializes it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17738467/1141471) to empty, 0 size string. The default ctor for scalars does nothing: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values.

Comment: Just to be clear with the example above, class B always results in the value 0:
https://ideone.com/XOcHNq
A: 0,0
B: 0,0
A: 145084416,0
B: 0,0
A: 145084432,0
B: 0,0
A: 145084416,0
//...

Answer (score 50):

They are both non-trivial.

They both have the same noexcept specification depending upon the noexcept specification of the bases and members.

The only difference I'm detecting so far is that if `Widget` contains a base or member with an inaccessible or deleted destructor:

```
struct A
{
private:
    ~A();
};

class Widget {
    A a_;
public:
#if 1
   virtual ~Widget() = default;
#else
   virtual ~Widget() {}
#endif
};
```

Then the `=default` solution will compile, but `Widget` won't be a destructible type.  I.e. if you try to destruct a `Widget`, you'll get a compile-time error.  But if you don't, you've got a working program.

Otoh, if you supply the *user-provided* destructor, then things won't compile whether or not you destruct a `Widget`:

```
test.cpp:8:7: error: field of type 'A' has private destructor
    A a_;
      ^
test.cpp:4:5: note: declared private here
    ~A();
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Interesting: in other words, with `=default;` the compiler won't generate the destructor unless it's used, and therefore won't trigger an error. This seems weird to me, even if not necessarily a bug. I can't imagine this behavior is *mandated* in the standard.

Comment: "Then the =default solution will compile"   No it will not. Just tested in vs.

Comment: What was the error message, and what version of VS?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you need to allocate the object on the heap for it to be a valid test - declaring a local `Widget` automatically tries to destroy it, so it won't compile, but writing `new Widget` would work in the `=default` case as long as you never `delete` it.