# Why using different (shared_ptr and normal) pointer constructors on the same class I get different results?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, default

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576055/how-is-default-different-from-for-default-constructor-and-destructor) I wrote my own little program (using code  from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23698999/675100)) and discovered things that confused me. Namely:

Having those classes:

```cpp
class A {
  public:
    A(){}
    int i;
    int j;
};

class B {
  public:
    B() = default;
    int i;
    int j;
};
```

I wrote 4 usages of those classes with different object construction usages:

```cpp
//1
A* pa = new A(); // followed by delete pa
B* pb = new B(); // followed by delete pb
//2
shared_ptr<A> pa = make_shared<A>();
shared_ptr<B> pb = make_shared<B>();
//3
shared_ptr<A> pa ( new A() );
shared_ptr<B> pb ( new B() );
//4
shared_ptr<A> pa ( new A );
shared_ptr<B> pb ( new B );
```

and after this I have used them to print their values like so:

```cpp
for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
  ...1..2..3..4
  cout << "A : " << pa->i << "," << pa->j << endl;
  cout << "B : " << pb->i << "," << pb->j << endl;
}
```

What I have received on the output surprised me:

```
//1
A : 0,0
B : 0,0
A : 7388176,0
B : 0,0
A : 7388208,0
B : 0,0

//2
A : 0,0
B : 0,0
A : 0,0
B : 0,0
A : 0,0
B : 0,0

//3
A : 0,0
B : 0,0
A : 25848848,0
B : 0,0
A : 25848880,0
B : 0,0

//4
A : 0,0
B : 0,0
A : 39619600,0
B : 39619664,0
A : 39619632,0
B : 39619696,0
```

While the first one is described in [aforementioned question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576055/how-is-default-different-from-for-default-constructor-and-destructor) what is happening in `//2`, `//3`, `//4`?

I used gcc 4.9.2 and 5.1.0 on Ubuntu 64 bit with the same results.

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/jENkaf)

Comment: how about providing the full code which reproduces the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first three code snippets *value-initialize* the objects constructed.

If the class's default constructor is not *user-provided*, value-initialization performs zero-initialization, and then call the default constructor; otherwise, it just calls the default constructor.

Now apply the discussion in the question linked.

For the `make_shared` case where you see all zeroes in both cases, that's just one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. Nothing more.

---

The final snippet *default-initializes* the objects constructed, which, for object of class type, means calling the default constructor, which in each case performs no initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize i and j. The behaviour is undefined then - random.

Comment: It is defined when using default constructor (not user defined) as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23698999/675100) (based on standard)