# Difference between virtual ~T(){} and virtual ~T() = default;

Tags: c++, c++11

When writing a `virtual` destructor, is there any functional or outwardly-discernible difference between having

```
virtual ~T() = default;
```

over

```
virtual ~T() {}
```

They both seem to have the same affect on anything from `type_traits` I could think to test with.

Comment: [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576055/how-is-default-different-from-for-default-constructor-and-destructor/13576544#13576544)

Answer (score 2):

They are effectively the same. While there is a difference with non-virtual destructors, once you stick `virtual` in there, it cannot be trivial anymore.

This is not the only time that `= default` leads to the generation of a non-trivial special member function. For example, if you have a member that has a non-trivial destructor, then using `= default` will not cause the creation of a trivial destructor for the containing type, even with a non-virtual destructor.

You should use `= default` anyway, just to make it clear what your intentions are.