# operator new() behaves differently when operator delete() is deleted depending on the existence of the default constructor

Tags: c++, delete-operator, default-constructor

Creating a new object of class C with operator new() gives an error here:

```
class C
{
public:
    C() {}
    virtual ~C() {}

    void operator delete(void*) = delete;
};


int main()
{
    C* c = new C;
}
```

with `C2280: 'void C::operator delete(void *)': function was explicitly deleted`

But when I replace `C() {}`
with `C() = default;`
or remove the line so that compiler inserts a default constructor(which I believe has the same effect with `= default`), the code will compile and run.

What are the differences between compiler-generated default constructor and user-defined default constructor that make this happen?

I got some hint in [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576055/how-is-default-different-from-for-default-constructor-and-destructor), but class C here(without user-provided constructor) isn't trivial since the destructor is virtual, right?

Compiled with latest Visual Studio, c++17.

Comment: Not sure, but I think the difference is that the defaulted constructor is `noexcept`

Comment: Can't reproduce with g++.   Similar diagnostic concerning `operator delete()` whether constructor is manually written or implicitly generated.   Which is consistent with my expectations -  since an exception may be thrown by the `new` expression, the compiler needs to access `operator delete()`.

Comment: @SebastianRedl you're right, adding `noexcept` will make the code compile, but how...?

Comment: @Peter The exception can only be thrown by the constructor, so if it is `noexcept` as SebastianRedl mentioned, then a call to `operator delete` needn't be included. Also g++ does only complain if the destructor is virtual. Otherwise it always compiles, even if the constructor is throwing.

Comment: @LeDYoM Your link is about parsing IP addresses, which seems to be irrelevant to the question. Did you post a wrong link?

Comment: @L.F. You are right. Edited.

Comment: Here is the link: https://godbolt.org/z/8y23BC

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What are the differences between compiler-generated default constructor and user-defined default constructor that make this happen?

`new` expression invokes the corresponding `operator new` and then calls the constructor. If the constructor throws an exception `new` expression must undo the effect of `operator new` (to avoid leaking memory) by calling the corresponding `operator delete`. If the latter is deleted `new` expression cannot call it which results in the compiler `error: use of deleted function 'static void C::operator delete(void*)'`.

A `noexcept` constructor cannot possibly throw an exception, hence, the corresponding `operator delete` is not necessary as it won't be called by a `new` expression. A `default` constructor of a trivial class is also a `noexcept` constructor. The presence of a virtual destructor requires `operator delete` to be non-deleted because the special *scalar deleting destructor* (an implementation detail to enable `delete` expression through the base class pointer) invokes `operator delete`.

It seems to be unspecified by the C++ standard whether the compiler must require `operator delete` to be non-deleted even if it cannot possibly be called by `new` expression. `gcc`, however, doesn't seem to be invoking the corresponding `operator delete` in `new` expression at all if it is `delete`d (posted a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93700)).