# C++ no default constructor found for Class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm receiving a common error with one of my classes, that of no default constructing being located for a specific class

Heres the class in question and its constructor

```
class Campaign {

public:
double funding;
double managerEffectiveness;
Date Day; //determine when they cant spend money anymore

Campaign(double funding, double managerEffectiveness, Date Day) {

funding = funding;
managerEffectiveness = managerEffectiveness;
Day =  Day;

}
};
```

The error is occurring at line 8, specifically Date Day. This variable of type Date can be used in a similar way in other constructors successfully, for example here is another class that utilizes the Date class. The exact error is no default constructor exists for class "Date"

```
class electrorateSupport: public Electrorates{

public:
Date Day;
double funding;
double financialEffectiveness();
double fudningImpact();


electrorateSupport(Date Day, double funding,double stanceDistriubtion, int Cluster)
:Electrorates(stanceDistriubtion,Cluster), Day(Day), funding(funding) {

Day = Day;
funding = funding;

}
);
```

This class is similar to the Campaign class, with the only big difference being it is a child class that inherits from another. I've been comparing these two classes to find any other differences which may cause my error but I can not be able to pinpoint any. I have also attempted to rewrite the class multiple times, still resulting in no definite issue. Thank you for any help!

EDIT date class has been provided

```
class Date {
     public:
     int Day;
     int Month;
     int Year;

     Date(int day, int month, int year) {
            this->Day = day;
            this->Month = month;
            this->Year = year;
        }

     void setDay(int day)
        {
            Day = day;
        }

        void setMonth(int month)
        {
          Month = month;
        }

       void setYear(int year)
        {
           Year = year;
        }

            int getDay()
        {
            return Day;
        }

        int getMonth()
        {
            return Month;
        }

        int getYear()
        {
            return Year;
        }

};
```

Comment: What does `Date` look like?

Comment: What is `Date`?

Comment: "`Day =  Day`" -- what exactly do you expect to accomplish by assigning an object to itself? Is this what you expect to happen here? If not, you're surely mistaken, because that's what ***will*** happen here. Seems like you need to learn how to use the initialization section of the constructor.

Comment: `electrorateSupport`'s constructor initializes `Day` in its constructor initializer list. `Campaign`'s constructor does not, which means it needs to be default-initialized, but it apparently lacks default constructor.

Comment: @Chipster I have provided it

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have provided it

Comment: You need to understand more about constructors, read this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c/

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thankyou for clearing that up its working now

Comment: @JimishFotariya -- From that site: `Default Constructors: Default constructor is the constructor which doesn’t take any argument. It has no parameters`-- The information at that site you linked to is incomplete or is misleading, as a lot of their information seems to be.  A default constructor *can* have arguments, it is just that all the arguments must have default values.  For example, `Day(int x = 0, int y = 0, int z=0);` is a default constructor.

Comment: @paulmckenzie, Technically default contructor doesn't "take" any arguments. But right, it can have default params. More constructtive defination is described at IBM knowledge center as `if a constructor has any arguments that do not have default values, it is not a default constructor` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzarg/cplr376.htm

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not with the Date class,

what a default constructor (the error message) is a constructor with no parameters,
so you need to have a constructor with no parameters even if it doesn't have a declaration.

This way:

```
Campaign() {}
```

that should solve your problem.

Note: error locations sometimes are confusing, don't ask me why.

Answer (score 0):

Once you provide a constructor with any kind of parameters, the compiler will no longer provide you with a default constructor [*without asking it to*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor).

You may still get your default constructor provided by the compiler by

```
Campaign()=default;
```

This, along with the other [special member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#special_member_functions) may be explicitly defaulted or deleted to force the compiler to generate one for you.

You can also just write an empty default constructor as well with

```
Campaign(){}
```

With [only slight changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576055/how-is-default-different-from-for-default-constructor-and-destructor) to the semantics