# c++ : code explanation for method prototype with const = 0

Tags: c++, virtual

I hava a class declaration with a piece of code that I do not understand :

```
class Weapon
{
  public:
    virtual void attack() const = 0;
};
```

What does the `const = 0` part means ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is a pure virtual method (`=0`) which is not supposed to change the data of the class (`const`). You should provide an implementation in one of the classes deriving from `Weapon`! See this: [Difference between a virtual function and a pure virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652198/difference-between-a-virtual-function-and-a-pure-virtual-function)

You are expected to derive from the `Weapon` (can be considered interface) concrete classes, such as `Axe` , `Shotgun`, etc ... where you will provide the `attack()` method.

Comment: Ok thanks, You're right because my `class Weapon` inherits from a `class AWeapon`.

Comment: Although, for `Shotgun`, the usual method of attacking does change the object, so `attack` should not be `const`.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig I've seen Hollywood movies, shotguns have an infinite supply of shells.. or maybe its because the 'ammunition' variable is never decremented because its const!

Comment: or maybe it's by default `iddqd` or `idkfa` :)

Comment: +1. Side note: the class should define a virtual destructor, otherwise it's not really usable as a polymorphic base class (as objects of derived classes couldn't be deleted through a `Weapon*`).

Answer (score 29):

Putting `const` after a member function indicates that the code inside it will not modify the containing object (except in the case of `mutable` members). This is useful because the compiler will report an error if you accidentally modify the object when you didn't intend to.

The `= 0` is not related to `const`. It's used in conjunction with `virtual` to indicate that the function is **pure virtual**. That means it must be overridden by a sub-class. Classes containing pure virtual functions are sometimes described as **abstract** because they cannot be directly instantiated.

Using your example, you would not be able to create an object of type `Weapon`, because the `attack()` function is not defined. You would have to create a sub-class, such as:

```
class Sword : public Weapon
{
public:
    void attack() const
    {
        // do something...
    }
};
```

Comment: This link might explain well about the const function https://www.tutorialspoint.com/const-member-functions-in-cplusplus