# an advanced declaration of a function?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I am previewing Ceres library of Google and have come across this declaration. I even thought this is wrong documentation, but the source code shows no difference:

```
bool Evaluate(double const* const* parameters,
                        double* residuals,
                        double** jacobians) const = 0;
```

As a c++ learner, I have to start step by step by breaking down this declaration:

1) what's with the double const* const*? shouldn't it be const double**?

2) the trailing part is const = 0? what does this mean?

I don't even know where to start to search for such an answer. Any standard documentation of c++?

Thanks!

Comment: To answer your second question, it is a [pure virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652198/difference-between-a-virtual-function-and-a-pure-virtual-function)

Comment: Thank you for both answers! it saves me lots of time to search for the keywords. I have no idea what they are called!