# can a pure virtual function has parameters?

Tags: c++, parameters, polymorphism, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

If I have have a classes  "Card" (Base Class) "CardOfType1" (Derived Class) and a class named "Player" having pointers of type 'Card' referring to 'CardOfType1'. Is it possible that we have a pure virtual function named 'playCard(Player enemyPlayer)'?

For more understanding, the code is given below

```
class Card
{
public:
    virtual void playCard(Player enemyPlayer) = 0;
};

class CardOfType1
{
public:
    void playCard(Player enemyPlayer)
    {
         //Some Code Goes here
    }
};

class Player
{
stack<Card *> deckOfCards
//.
//.
//.

};
```

Comment: Yes, you can...

Comment: Of course you can, otherwise it would be pretty much useless in most cases. Oh and when creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (even a small and incomplete (which is okay in a few cases) one like you have done) try to make it as complete and valid as possible, including having the inheritance correct.

Comment: You also asked a different question literally minutes ago, I can't imagine you did any good research on this topic. Please do that first before you ask a question.

Comment: Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: @StoryTeller it was nothing to do with me saying `delete(new Player()->playCard(this));`  I swear

Comment: What exactly makes you suspect we cannot?

Comment: @UKMonkey what the hell.

Comment: @Quentin - A running gag between UKMonkey and myself. Pay us no mind, those comments often clean themselves up.

Comment: @Neijwiert
I am just a learner and was not able to find the answer of this question here
Just due to this I asked this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, a `PVF` can have parameters.

```
virtual void playCard(Player enemyPlayer) = 0;
```

here `= 0` (is not assigning), Simply we are informing to compiler that function will be `pure` and does not having any body(where its declared, in that class), but it can have parameter.

From the n4659 `C++` standard

> A pure virtual function need be defined only if called with, or as if
>   with (15.4), the qualified-id syntax (8.1).

```
class shape {
  point center;
  public:
  virtual void rotate(int) = 0; // pure virtual
  virtual void draw() = 0; // pure virtual
};
```

But there is another observation

> A function declaration cannot provide both a pure-specifier and a
>   definition — end note ]

```
struct C {
   virtual void f() = 0 { };
};
```

Comment: not quite;  =0 and "does not have a body" are not mutually exclusive.  One can have `virtual void playCard(Player derp) = 0 {std::cout << "here";} `  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609299/use-cases-of-pure-virtual-functions-with-body) question may be of use

Comment: @UKMonkey I mean in `base class` a `PVF` can't have body, in respective `derived class` it should have. Correct me If I am wrong

Comment: @UKMonkey Not in the same declaration.

Comment: @achal You can provide an implementation for a PVF, but it has to be out-of-line (i.e. not as part of the in-class declaration).

Comment: @Angew thanks the one - thanks :)  although I think VS has allowed me to do it inline in the past - but what VS do and the standard say aren't always the same ;)

Comment: @Angew Ok. Thanks for more clarification.