# Calling methods of class derived from an abstract class [C++]

Tags: c++, abstract-class

You'll have to forgive me if this is a really basic question; I haven't used C++ this much in a long time so I've forgotten how a lot of it works.

Anyway, I have a base class and a couple derived classes like this (super oversimplified, but the gist is the same):

```
class Base
{
public:
   Base () { }
   int SomeFunction (int x, int y); // abstract definition
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
   Derived1() : Base() { }
   int SomeFunction (int x, int y)
   {
      // actual implementation
      return 4;
   }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
   Derived2() : Base() { }
   int SomeFunction (int x, int y)
   {
      // actual implementation
      return 7;
   }
};
```

Later on in `main` I have a list of `Base` objects:

```
Base *baseobjects[10];
```

Later I fill that array with instances of `Derived1` and `Derived2`. That works with `baseobjects[i] = &newDerived1` (where `newDerived1` is an instance of the `Derived1` class). That's all fine.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to later iterate through the `baseobjects` array and  call `SomeFunction` on every instance in the list *without explicitly knowing which derived class I'm using*. I've done this in C# and it works fine, but apparently my C++ syntax is off:

```
int result = baseobjects[i]->SomeFunction(a, b);
```

That gives me a `LNK2019` error when I try to compile, apparently because it's looking at the `Base` class for the implementation and it isn't there. I'm assuming I have to use some pointer tricks to get it to look at the proper derived method, but nothing I've tried yet has worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: You forgot to put semicolons (`;`) after each class definition.

Comment: @ereOn - Well, not in my real code I didn't. I'll fix that here.

Comment: Also... you might as well fix `Derived1` and `Derived2` : as the code stands, none of these classes inherits from `Base`. ;)

Comment: that's what I get for rewriting the simpler forms by hand. oh well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your method should be declared `virtual`. And in your case, probably **pure** `virtual`.

```
class Base
{
public:
   Base () { }
   virtual int SomeFunction (int x, int y) = 0; // abstract definition
};
```

Note that, while this is not absolutely required, you might as well declare a `virtual` destructor. Do it if you ever delete a derived instance trough a pointer of the base class.

```
class Base
{
public:
   //Base () {} // This is not required, the default provided constructor is similar.
   virtual ~Base() {} // virtual destructor.
   virtual int SomeFunction (int x, int y) = 0; // abstract definition
};
```

### Edit:

Also, regarding the link error you posted:

Either you forgot the `= 0`, either you are calling `Base::SomeFunction()` from somewhere.

As *Thomas Edleson* points out, `= 0` does not mean that your function has no implementation: it can have one, but it only requires the derived classes to (re)implement it to not being *abstract*.

If you are interested in this topic, I suggest you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089083/pure-virtual-function-with-implementation).

Comment: Either make it pure.. or add `{}` after the function name.

Comment: When I try this and compile, I get a different linking error: `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int__thiscall Base::SomeFunction(int x, int y)"` and another: `error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`.

Comment: @Nawaz: wouldn't the method lack a `return` value with an empty body (`{}`) ? Or is it some specific syntax I've never heard of ?

Comment: @Nawaz - Adding `{}` forces me to write an implementation in the base class, which results in a slew of other errors since `Base` is no longer abstract.

Comment: @Andrew S. Arnold: Did you put the `= 0` ? If so, the linker should never ask for this function because it knows it has no implementation. Be sure to clean your working directory (all old object files) and try again.

Comment: @ereOn: Pure virtual does not mean "has no implementation".

Comment: @ereOn: My point was : either make it pure, or define it. Since I was eating, so I typed it with my left hand, I made it as minimal as possible for me :D

Comment: @Thomas Edleson: You're right good point. My wording was inaccurate. I will update my answer in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas Edleson: Well, once again my wording was a bit off... I meant... well : read the updated answer, you'll see what I meant ;)

Comment: With regards to the error, yeah I'd omitted the `=0`; I'm getting different problems now—an "access violation reading location 0xcccccccc" when I run the program. Probably something to do with how I'm instantiating my derived classes.

Comment: @Andrew S. Arnold: My guess is you have some other mistake not shown in this question. However, your problem regarding the inheritance and virtual function should be solved. You should probably ask another question for your other problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override a method, it must be virtual.

```
class Base
{
public:
   Base () { }
   virtual int SomeFunction (int x, int y); // abstract definition
}
```

Seccond thing is that your derivated classes did not extends of your base-class.

```
class Derived1 : public Base
{ 
 public:
    Derived1() : Base() { }
    int SomeFunction (int x, int y)
    {
        // actual implementation
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the member function SomeFunction()

1. virtual
2. abstract

So the declaration for Base should look like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() { }
    virtual int SomeFunction(int x, int y) = 0;
};
```

You can omit the virtual keyword in the derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

To just slightly elaborate on ereOn's answer, you *do* need to declare you base class function (ie: your abstract definition) in order for your derived classes to be able to override it. What he didn't clarify though is that other than that, what you've posted is fine (that is, the calls to the function you posted will then work without any modification).

Note also, that if you're after a pure abstract definition, you should append `= 0` to your function declaration as follows:

```
class Base
{
public:
   Base () { }
   virtual int SomeFunction (int x, int y) = 0; // pure abstract definition
};
```

This lets the compiler know that classes derived from `Base` must supply their own implementation of `SomeFunction`.

Comment: Hmmm... getting closer. This compiles, but when running I get an access violation error at the line where I call the function (`int result = baseobjects[i]->SomeFunction(a, b);`).

Comment: Not true; pure virtual specifies that derived classes (at least one in the hierarchy) must override the method, but the base can still provide an implementation.

Comment: see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089083/pure-virtual-function-with-implementation) for more details.

Comment: @Thomas: true. I even actually knew that - dunno why I wrote it that way. I'll change it to be more accurate.