# It is said abstract class for a virtual function that is implemented. It works with three of four similar implementations

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

It seems only be a problem with circle.cpp even if the code looks the same in point.cpp.
I've been looking at the code a long time now and I haven't found anything different in the two files. 
Here is the error message:

```
>------ Build started: Project: ou5, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  circle.cpp
1>  ou5.cpp
1>c:\users\jonas\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ou5\ou5\shapeptr.h(52): error C2259: 'Shape' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'Shape *Shape::clone(void) const' : is abstract
1>          c:\users\jonas\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ou5\ou5\shape.h(21) : see declaration of 'Shape::clone'
1>ou5.cpp(20): error C2259: 'Shape' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'Shape *Shape::clone(void) const' : is abstract
1>          c:\users\jonas\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ou5\ou5\shape.h(21) : see declaration of 'Shape::clone'
1>ou5.cpp(27): error C2259: 'Shape' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'Shape *Shape::clone(void) const' : is abstract
1>          c:\users\jonas\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ou5\ou5\shape.h(21) : see declaration of 'Shape::clone'
1>  point.cpp
1>  polygon.cpp
1>  rectangle.cpp
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The code for the base class with a pure virtual function:

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

class Shape
{
public:
    Shape()
    {
        cout << "Shape constructor" << endl;
    }
    Shape(double xval, double yval)
    {
        x = xval;
        y = yval;
    }


    virtual Shape* clone() const = 0;
    virtual double area()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    virtual void print() const{}
    virtual ostream& printf(ostream &os){return os;}
    /* // Copy constructor
    Shape(const Shape *sp)
    {
        // Copy the string into our newly allocated memory
        sp =this->clone();
    }*/

    /*Shape & operator=(const Shape & sptr)
        {
    if(this!= &sptr)
    {
        *this = sptr.clone();
    }
    return *this;
}*/

    double getx() const
    {
        return x;
    }
    double gety() const
    {
        return y;
    }
    virtual ~Shape() {cout << "Shape raderas av destruktor" <<endl; }
        protected:
    double x;       //Attribut
    double y;       //Attribut
    Shape *sp;

};

#endif
```

Point.h that is working:

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H
#include "shape.h"
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
class Point : public Shape
{
public:
    Point()
    {
        cout << "Point constructor" << endl;
    }
    Point(double x, double y, double sz) : Shape(x,y), size(sz)
    {
        cout << "Point constructor" << endl;
    }
    void las(istream &is)
    {
        is >> x >> y >> size;
    }
    ostream& printf(ostream &os) ;
    void print() const;

    double area();
    Shape* clone() const;
    virtual ~Point(){cout << "Point raderas av destruktor" << endl;}
private:
    double size;        //Attribut
};
#endif
```

point.cpp:

```
#include "point.h"
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

Shape* Point::clone() const { return new Point( *this); }

void Point::print() const
    {

    cout << "POINT: ";
    cout <<"(" << this->x<<"," << this->y << ")" << this->size << endl;
    }
ostream& Point::printf(ostream &os) 
    {
    os << "POINT: ";
    os <<"(" << this->x<<"," << this->y << ")" << this->size << endl;
    return os;
    }

    double Point::area()
    {
        return size;
    }
```

The files with a problem. First circle.h:

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H
#include "shape.h"
using namespace std;
#define M_PI 3.141592654
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle()
    {
        cout << "Circle constructor" << endl;
    }
    Circle(double x, double y, double rad) : Shape(x,y), radie(rad)
    {
        cout << "Circle constructor" << endl;
    }
    void las(istream &is)
    {
        is >> x >> y >> radie;
    }
    ostream& printf(ostream &os);
    double area(); 
    void print() const;
    Shape* clone() const;
    virtual ~Circle(){cout << "Circle raderas av destruktor" << endl;}
private:
    double radie;       //Attribut
};
#endif
```

Then circle.cpp:

```
#include "circle.h"
using namespace std;
#include <ostream>

Shape* Circle::clone() const {return new Circle( *this);}
double Circle::area()
    {
        double tmparea;
        tmparea = M_PI * radie * radie;
        return tmparea;
    }
    void Circle::print() const
    {
    cout << "CIRCLE: ";
    cout <<"(" << this->x<<"," << this->y << ")" << this->radie << endl;
    }
    ostream& Circle::printf(ostream &os) 
    {
    os << "CIRCLE: ";
    os <<"(" << this->x<<"," << this->y << ")" << this->radie << endl;
    return os;
    }
```

The problem is with `clone` and it looks the same in the file working and the not working            file. The working file is `point.cpp` but it also works with two other files not posted here.

I add shapeptr.h here:

```
#ifndef SHAPEPTR_H
#define SHAPEPTR_H
#include "shape.h"
#include "circle.h"
#include "point.h"
#include "polygon.h"
#include "rectangle.h"
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



class ShapePtr
{
 public:
     ShapePtr()
     {
         sptr = 0;
         numshapes = numshapes + 1;

     }
  ShapePtr(Shape * v)//: Shape(v->getx(),v->gety())
  {
      sptr = v;
      numshapes = numshapes + 1;

  }
  // Copy constructor
ShapePtr(const Shape &sp)
{
        // Copy the string into our newly allocated memory
        sptr = sp.clone();
}
const ShapePtr & ShapePtr::operator=(const Shape & sp)
{
    if(this->sptr!= &sp)
    {
        sptr = sp.clone();
    }
    return *this;
}
  ~ShapePtr(){
      numshapes = numshapes - 1;  
      cout << "ShapePtr raderas av destruktor" << endl;
  }  

 Shape getshape()
 {
     return *sptr;
 }
 private:
  Shape *sptr;
public:
  static int numshapes;

  friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, ShapePtr & sp);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const ShapePtr & sp);
};

int ShapePtr::numshapes = 0;

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const ShapePtr & sp)
{
    os << sp.sptr->printf(os);
    return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream &is, ShapePtr & sp)
{
    string check;
    while(!is.eof())
    {
        is >> check;
        if(check == "Circle")
        {
        Circle cir;
        cir.las( is );
        sp = ShapePtr(new Circle(cir));
        return is;

        }
        if(check == "Polygon")
        {
        Polygon pol;
        pol.las( is );
        sp = ShapePtr(new Polygon(pol));
        return is;

        }
        if(check == "Point")
        {
        Point poi;
        poi.las( is );
        sp = ShapePtr(new Point(poi));
        return is;

        }
        if(check == "Rectangle")
        {
        Rectangle rec;
        rec.las( is );
        sp = ShapePtr(new Rectangle(rec));
        return is;

        }
    }

    }


#endif
```

Comment: The error is in `shapeptr.h`.

Comment: You should not put "using namespace std;" in an include file. It brings in the whole std namespace to anyone trying to use your .h file.

Comment: The code as you have posted seems to compile for me. Did you copy-paste it exactly? What was the error message? Secondly let me strongly reiterate what @MikMik said: Never use `using` in headers (there may be exceptions, for example within inline methods but don't worry about that).

Comment: I did copy and paste exactly

Comment: Shapeptr.h is just trying to make an instance of an abstract class. The problem is probably not there.

Comment: But it is not abstract since it's implemented in circle.cpp. The same function is implemented in point.cpp and no error comes for that one.

Comment: @user2224247 `Circle` is a different `type` than `Shape` so you can create an instance of `Circle` because it is `concrete` and does not have any abstract methods. This may be helpul http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr142.htm

Comment: The base class is Shape and the two derived classes Point and Circle and actually two more. Point works fine but not Circle.

Comment: @user2224247 To remove confusion, the terms for `Circle` and `Point` are concrete classes and `Shape` is an abstract class. I think seeing `Shapeptr.h` will make the problem clear otherwise I don't think we can help more and most likely it will garner votes to close.

Comment: @juanchopanza In case you are curious the problem was indeed in `shapeptr.h`

Comment: What was it? Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments you are attempting to make an instance of an `abstract class` in `Shapeptr.h` which is not [valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131567/why-cant-we-create-an-instance-of-an-abstract-class). The point where you attempt to create this instance is here:

```
Shape getshape()
{
     return *sptr;
}
```

As Mark B. pointed out the fix is to change the return type to `Shape&`.

Comment: It should not be abstract since it is implemented in circle.cpp. The same implementation is in point.cpp and it compiles fine.

Comment: But it should not be abstract since I have implemented it in circle.cpp. The problem is that it does not accept the implementation.

Comment: You should note that the fix is to change the return type to `Shape&`.

Comment: @user2224247 In `Point` you are returning a `Shape*` which is fine since a `pointer` or `reference` can refer to a derived class, i.e. they can act polymorphically.

Comment: I am returning Shape* in circle.cpp also.

Comment: I'll try an other compiler tomorrow