# Invalid abstract type

Tags: c++, abstract-class, pure-virtual

So I have a problem with an abstract class!

This is the Product.h

```
#ifndef PRODUCT_H
#define PRODUCT_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Product
{
    private:
        string description;
        int d,m,y;
        float weight;

    public:
        Product();
        Product(string description,int d,int m,int y, float weight);
        void print();
        virtual bool isExpiring()=0;
};

#endif
```

This is Product.cpp

```
#include "Product.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Product::Product()
{
    description="";
    d=0;
    m=0;
    y=0;
    weight=0.0;
}

Product::Product(string description,int d,int m,int y, float weight)
{
    this->description=description;
    this->d=d;
    this->m=m;
    this->y=y;
    this->weight=weight;
}

void Product::print()
{
    cout << "Description: " << description<<endl;
    cout << "Expiration date: " << d <<"/" << m << "/" << y << endl;
    cout << "Weight: " << weight << endl;
}
```

This is ShortTermProduct.h

```
#ifndef SHORTTERMPRODUCT_H
#define SHORTTERMPRODUCT_H
#include "Product.h"

class ShortTermProduct : public Product
{
    public:
        ShortTermProduct();
        void Print();
        bool isExpiring();
};

#endif
```

This is LongTermProduct.h

```
#ifndef LONGTERMPRODUCT_H
#define LONGTERMPRODUCT_H
#include "ShortTermProduct.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class LongTermProduct 
{
    private:
        int lifetime;
        string open, open_date;

    public:
        LongTermProduct(int lifetime,string open,string open_date);
        void print();
        bool isExpiring();
};

#endif
```

And finally this is Fridge.h

```
#ifndef FRIDGE_H
#define FRIDGE_H
#include "LongTermProduct.h"
class Fridge : public LongTermProduct
{
    private:
        Product products[10];

    public:
        fridge();
        void addShortTermProduct (ShortTermProduct p);
        void addLongTermProduct (LongTermProduct p);
        void printFridgeProducts();
        bool isExpiring();
};

#endif
```

The errors I am getting are these:

- [Error] invalid abstract type 'Product' for 'products'
- [Error] cannot declare field 'Fridge::products' to be of abstract type 'Product'

Any help would be grate !Thanks in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't we create an instance of an abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131567/why-cant-we-create-an-instance-of-an-abstract-class)

Comment: Which part of "cannot declare field 'Fridge::products' to be of abstract type 'Product'" you did not understand? `Product` is an abstract class, and you are attempting to declare a class member that's an array of abstract classes. This is not valid C++. The End.

Comment: Also note that it is generally wise to declare abstract base class's destructor `virtual`, too.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`virtual bool isExpiring()=0;` is a pure virtual function (abstract), therefore `Product` is an abstract class.

```
Product products[10];
```

What you are doing here is trying to create 10 objects of an abstract type `Product`. But you cannot create an object from an abstract class. What you want are `Product` pointers which can point to pointers of derived classes:

```
Product** products = new Product*[10];
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `for(auto &i: products) i = new ShortTermProduct;`

Comment: @bipll Well, that was a rethorical question.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurred because the `Product` class has a pure virtual method, therefore you should use pointer to declare it. if you want to use c++ fixed array size, I suggest you to look at `std::array` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/)

```
std::array<Product*, 50> products;
```