# C++ Invalid New Expression Of Abstract Class Type

Tags: c++

I get this error when using c++. I tried other solutions such as using a shared pointer but with no avail. Here is my code :

Main.cpp:

```cpp
int main() {
    game_init();
    cout << items.at(0).name << endl; 
    while(true) game_tick();
    return 0;
}
```

Item.h:

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H
#include "../Rooms/Room.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Item {
    public :
        Room location;
        string name, desc;
        //Item(string, string, Room);
        virtual void use() = 0; 
        
};
vector <Item> items;

/*
Item::Item(string in_name, string in_desc, Room in_location) {
    name = in_name;
    desc = in_desc;
    location = in_location;
    
}*/
#endif
```

Items.h:

```cpp
#ifndef ITEMS_H
#define ITEMS_H
#include "OldKey.h"

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

vector <shared_ptr<Item>> all_items;
OldKey   old_key;

void items_init() {
    items.push_back(old_key);
}
#endif
```

The error is Invalid New Expression of Abstract class Type "Item". Hope I can fix this, keep in mind I am new to c++ so please try to explain the solution or workaround simply, thanks.

Comment: I think this will be helpful for you to understand with abstract class: [Why can't we create an instance of an abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131567/why-cant-we-create-an-instance-of-an-abstract-class)

Comment: I found a way to remove the error message. In the item class I defined what use is in case the subclasses didn't define it. But this means if I were to use the command items.at(anyindex).use(), it would just give the predefined function. I'm stuck on what to do, help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate a class (`Item`) with a pure virtual function (`use`). This is not allowed. To fix this you could

- Create a subclass that implements the `use` function and then instantiate that subclass instead of `Item`.
- Make the function virtual but not pure virtual, i.e., remove the `= 0` and then provide a default implementation in the `Item` class. A subclass can then provide its own implementation of `use` by overriding the function.

Note that your definition of `vector<Item> items` looks fishy. If you attempt to store a subclass of `Item` in this vector then this will be converted to an instance of `Item` and all information of the subclass will be lost. You may want to change this to a vector of pointers, for example.

Comment: I did the latter workaround earlier, but when I called use I was getting the parent class method and not the over ridden method. To fix this do I just change vector<Item> items to vector <*Item> items

Comment: Ok, I found out how to solve it using the pointer. Thanks for explaining.