# Allocation of Abstract Type Object

Tags: c++, virtual, abstract, allocation

I have read this thread here:

["Cannot allocate an object of abstract type" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352706/cannot-allocate-an-object-of-abstract-type-error)

But I think it does not answer my case...

I have the files:

base.h

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {

    public:

        Base(){
            protected_member = 0;
        }
        Base(int pm_val): protected_member(pm_val) {cout << "created Base." << endl;}
        virtual ~Base(){cout << "deleted Base." << endl;}

        virtual int access_Base_pm() = 0;

    protected:

        int protected_member;

};

#endif
```

base.cpp (redudant I guess)

```
#include "base.h"
#include "derived.h"
```

derived.h

```
#ifndef DERIVED_H
#define DERIVED_H

#include <iostream>
#include "base.h"

using namespace std;

class Base;

class Derived: public Base {

    public:

        Derived(){cout << "created Derived." << endl;}
        ~Derived(){cout << "deleted Derived." << endl;}

        int access_Base_pm();

};

#endif
```

derived.cpp

```
#include "derived.h"
#include "base.h"

int Derived::access_Base_pm(){
    return protected_member;
}
```

When I run

main_1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "base.h"
#include "derived.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Base* base;
    base = new Derived();
    cout << base->access_Base_pm() << endl;

}
```

everything seems to be fine.

But when I run

main_2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "base.h"
#include "derived.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Base* base = new Base;
    base = new Derived();
    cout << base->access_Base_pm() << endl;

}
```

or

main_3.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "base.h"
#include "derived.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Base(5)* base;
    base = new Derived();
    cout << base->access_Base_pm() << endl;

}
```

I get "error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Base’"

Why? I don't get it. As it says in the other thread, I am accessing the object only via a pointer... what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do a new of Base because that it is the abstract type.

```
Base* base = new Base;
```

is illegal

```
Base* base = new Derived();
```

is OK but for the reasons explained here : [Is no parentheses on a constructor with no arguments a language standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318650/is-no-parentheses-on-a-constructor-with-no-arguments-a-language-standard) I prefer:

```
base = new Derived;
```

Also I don't know if this compiles :

```
Base(5)* base;
```

What is your intent with that statement ? 
Based on your comment it should be

```
Base* base = new Base(5);
```

or

```
Base base(5);
```

if no pointer is needed, but this would not work because Base is abstract.
And I cannot do it with Derived because then Derived has a missing constructor with a parameter. So you would need :

```
class Derived: public Base {

public:

    Derived(){cout << "created Derived." << endl;}
    Derived(){cout << "created Derived." << endl;}
    ~Derived(int pm_val):Base(pm_val){cout << "deleted Derived." << endl;}

    int access_Base_pm();

};

Base* base = new Derived(5);
```

or

```
Derived derived(5);
Base* base = &derived;
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't really understand. I thought this would be the same as with any other class Classname* classinstance = new Classname. Can you elaborate or tell me where this explained?

Comment: `base = new Derived();` is by no means wrong if base has already been declared, which is the case here.  `Base * base = new Derived();` is much better but its important to make that distinction.

Comment: My intent with that statement was to create an instance of Base with parameter 5 that base is a pointer to.

Comment: Answering your edit: I still don't understand. The other thread says you need pointers to abstract classes.

Comment: You only need pointers to abstract types if you want to program towards those abstract types. A good OO program does just that. But this example is somewhat academic.

Comment: which ~ do you mean ? but in any case as soon as you have a virtual method it is wise to create a virtual destructor too.

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks! I was talking about the destructor with parameters. You apparently just have put the ~ at the wrong place... right?

Comment: ok then please upvote this answer or mark it as solution, or both.

Answer (score 0):

main_1.cpp seems fine, because it is fine.

main_2.cpp does something that is fairly interesting

```
Base(5) * base;
```

Now, if `Base(5)` where some kind of type - which it is not - this would be a declaration of a pointer variable. However, `Base(5)` is actually a temporary variable (that is multiplied with an object with the name `base` that does not even exist in your code), created by constructing a variable of type `Base` and passing its constructor a `5`. This is exactly what the question you linked explains as forbidden.

main_3.cpp blatantly does `new Base` which is exactly what the question you linked explores - `Base` is abstract and you try to create an object of that type.