# Allocating an object of abstract class type c++ xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, pure-virtual

TreeInterface.h

```
#ifndef TreeInterface_h
#define TreeInterface_h
#include"PreconditionException.h"
#include"NotFoundException.h"
//#include"Tree.hpp"
template<class ItemType>
class TreeInterface //: public binarySearchTree<ItemType>
{
  virtual void clear()=0;
  virtual  bool isEmpty()const=0;
  virtual int getHeight()=0;
  virtual ItemType getRootData() const throw(precondViolated)=0;
  virtual bool add(const ItemType& item)=0;
  virtual void setItem()=0;
  virtual int getNumberOfNodes()const=0;
  //virtual ItemType getEntry(const ItemType& anEntry) const throw(NotFoundException)=0;
  // int getNumberOfNodes()const;
  //virtual void setRootData(const ItemType& item)=0;
  //virtual void inorder()=0;
};
#endif /* TreeInterface_h */
```

I try to create a binary tree but I have a problem with abstract class. When I try to create a new instance of class `binarySearchTree` it gives me an error: `Allocating an object of abstract class type "binarySearchTree"`. I checked all my functions.I don't know what to do. I thought the problem is including different files such as Node.cpp, I am not sure about it .I would appreciate some help.

Tree.h

```
#ifndef Tree_h
#define Tree_h
#include"TreeInterface.h"
#include"Node.h"
//#include"tree.cpp" // should be correct
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include"PreconditionException.h"
#include "NotFoundException.h"
using namespace std;
template<class ItemType>
class binarySearchTree: public TreeInterface<ItemType>
{
private:
    node<ItemType>* rootPtr;
protected:
int getHeightHelp(node<ItemType>* subTreePtr)const;

void destroyTree(node<ItemType>* subTreePtr);

node<ItemType>* balancedAdd(node<ItemType>* subTreePtr,node<ItemType>* newNodePtr);

node<ItemType>* copyTree(const node<ItemType>* treePtr) const;
public:
binarySearchTree();

binarySearchTree(const ItemType& rootItem);

binarySearchTree(const ItemType& rootItem,binarySearchTree<ItemType>* leftPart,binarySearchTree<ItemType>* rightPart);

binarySearchTree(const binarySearchTree<ItemType>& treePtr);

void clear();
bool isEmpty()const;
int getHeight();
bool add(const ItemType& item);
ItemType getRootData() const throw(precondViolated);
int getNumberOfNodes(node<ItemType>* subtree)const;
void setItem(ItemType item);
};
```

`
Node.h

```
#ifndef Node_h
#define Node_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class ItemType>
class node
{
private:
ItemType data;
node<ItemType>* left;
node<ItemType>* right;
public:
node();
node(const ItemType &newdata);
node(const ItemType& item,node<ItemType>* leftPtr,node<ItemType>*      rightPtr);
ItemType getNodeItem();
ItemType* getLeftPtr();
ItemType* getRightPtr();
void setLeft(node<ItemType>* newleft);
void setRight(node<ItemType>* newright);
void setNodeItem(ItemType& item);
bool isLeaf() const;
};
```

The error comes  when I try to create a new instance of binarySearchTree.
 main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include"Tree.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int num=11;
binarySearchTree<int>* node=new binarySearchTree<int>();  //the error is here. Allocating an object of abstract class type "binarySearchTree" 
node->add(9);
node->isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Is every single line of this code required to reproduce your problem?  It seems unlikely.  Please check out [mcve] to learn the appropriate way to post code in a question for stack overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cannot allocate an object of abstract type" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352706/cannot-allocate-an-object-of-abstract-type-error)

Answer (score 1):

As xaxxon has pointed out with the link, if you have an abstract class (where virtual function = 0) then all of the functions in the base class need to be over-ridden in order to instantiate an object of the derived class. Your compiler error is telling you that you have not over-ridden all of the functions.

In your case your problem is slightly more subtle. Consider the following:

```
class Abstract
{
public:
    virtual bool MyFunction(int x) = 0;
};

class Concrete : public Abstract
{
public:
    bool MyFunction()       // This does not override Abstract::MyFunction because it is "overloaded", parameters are different
    {
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Concrete concrete;
    return 0;
}
```

Although it might appear that we are over-riding MyFunction, this is not the case because the parameters are different (base class had int x). So its not the same function and Concrete is actually still an abstract class.

Compare your functions: `void setItem(ItemType item);` is not going to over-ride `virtual void setItem()=0;` in the base class

Comment: You shouldn't answer duplicate questions in that question.  If you don't think the duplicate has sufficient information, you should add an answer there to keep the information centralized -- but most of the time the existing answer is sufficient and additional answers just make it take longer to get to the best answers.