# virtual function in derived class naming

Tags: c++, class, virtual

I'm trying to determine how to name my virtual function in the derived class.

```
Base.h
class Base 
{
public:
    virtual void Virtual() = 0;
};

Derived.h
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void Virtual();
};

Derived.cpp
Derived::Virtual() // or Base::Virtual
{
  cout << "Derived Virtual.\n";
}
```

Do I use Derived::Virtual or Base::Virtual in the implementation file and what are issues with going either way?

Comment: Why do you think you would need `Base::` when you wan to define the function for `Derived`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

`Derived::Virtual` will define the overridden function, while `Base::Virtual` will define the base class function. Both can be done. You can't skip defining the former, that is, `Derived::Virtual` since it's not pure virtual, and once it gets called when you have't defined it, there's gong to be a linking error.

It does make sense to define `Base::Virtual` to provide some common behavior, and then call that function without using the virtual dispatch by qualifying it fully like this:

```
void Derived::Virtual() {
    Base::Virtual();
    std::cout << Derived::Virtual() < "\n";
}
```

See [C++ pure virtual function have body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481941/c-pure-virtual-function-have-body) and [Does it make any sense to define "pure" virtual functions in the base class itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063971/does-it-make-any-sense-to-define-pure-virtual-functions-in-the-base-class-itse) for reference.

Comment: That's quite an anti-pattern, because a programmer can easily forget the call and the compiler will not notice, resulting in strange run-time bugs. A better approach is to have a **public non-virtual** function which has the common behaviour and calls a **private pure virtual** function to be implemented in the derived class.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Right, that's the template method. I actually haven't looked at it this way, just quoted the common idiom of calling a pure virtual function by fully qualifying it. What are the real use cases of this C++ functionality?