# c++ abstract class with some implementation

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I want to make an abstract class in c++ with a single, but with some default implementation.
so that every class that inherits it will have default behavior but you cant create an instance of the base class.
but if i mark foo as pure virtual, I can't add an implementation to it.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo() =0; //Now I can't add foo implementation
};
```

My solution was to not have it as a pure virtual, and just hide the constructor.
I'm wondering if its possible to mark the class as pure, but still have some implementation?

Comment: What, exactly, is wrong with "my solution was to not have it as a pure virtual, and just hide the constructor"?  That sounds perfectly reasonable.

Comment: There's no problem with providing an implementation for a pure virtual function. But I agree with James, your original idea is probably best.

Comment: Using a private constructor is probably the way to go. Or if you have a C++11 compiler you can mark the constructor as [deleted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Explicitly_defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: You'll need to make it protected (and not deleted) to be able to instantiate derived classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You [can add an implementation to a pure virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089083/). Classes that derive can use the default implementation by explicitly invoking the base-class-method.