# pure virtual function, how it works

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I have a question about pure virtual functions. I am not clear about how it works and when we need to use pure virtual functions. This is the example that I do not understand:

```
file.h

class A
{
public :
            A();
            ~A();

            virtual void func1(void) = 0;
            virtual UINT32 func2(void) = 0;
            UINT32 initialize(void) = 0;
}


file.cpp

UINT32 A:initialize (void)
{
            func1();
            func2();
            return (result);
}
```

Can anyone explain in detail what this example actually does and what the result is?
I really appreciate your help and knowledge.  Thank you very much.

Comment: This will not compile. Are you sure you did't mean `UINT32 result = func2();` instead of just `func2();` in the middle of the A:initialize function?

Comment: Yes, I think that is a mistake. You are correct. Thank you..:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [pure virtual function with implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089083/pure-virtual-function-with-implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note, the declaration for `initialize()` should not be virtual, and the implementation of `initialize()` should return `func2()` probably. As this is an example, it doesn't really matter what `initialize()` does, but it should compile correctly.)

The primary purpose of virtual functions is to achieve polymorphism.

Class `A` defines two pure virtual methods, and `initialize` calls them. This allows code in the program to initialize something of type `A` without being aware of the subclass. There may be many subclasses of `A`, and each may do something slightly differently within `func1()` and `func2()`. Since the code that only knows about `A` is sometimes initializing objects of different types through `A`, `A` can be referred to as a polymorphic type.

```
class B : public A {
    void func1 () { std::cout << "B::func1" << std::endl; }
    UINT32 func2 () { return 1; }
};

class C : public A {
    void func1 () { std::cout << "C::func1" << std::endl; }
    UINT32 func2 () { return 2; }
};

void call_initialize (A *a) {
    std::cout << a->initialize()  << std::endl;
}

B b;
C c;
call_initialize(&b);
call_initialize(&c);
```

Results in the output:

```
B::func1
1
C::func1
2
```

This is an example of polymorphic behavior, because the output is different depending on if `A` was subclassed by `B` or by `C`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Your example is really helpful!!..Thank you very much..:)

Comment: @SitiHaslinaMohdZulkafli: You're welcome. +1 on your question.

Answer (score 0):

The functions `func1` & `func2` are not implemented in A (as per the code shown).
If they are implemented, then they are called. If there is a derived class for A and if the object for the derived class is created polymorphically,  i.e.

```
class B : public A
{
 .....
};

A* obj = new B();

obj->initialize();
```

Then func1() and func2() of B's version are called if B implemented them.

As mentioned in the comment by Ethan, you are not taking the result from func2().
So you need either write

```
UINT32 result = func2();
```

or

```
return func2();
```

Comment: owh..you mean, there is a mistake in this code right?..I just realize..Yes, maybe its typo error..I am not so sure but your help is really appreciated. Thank you..:)

Comment: Neither `A::func1` nor `A::func2` will be called here, even if they are implemented, since they are pure virtual. Only derived classes that override them can be instantiated, and those overrides will be called instead.