# Default pure virtual implementation C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pure virtual function with implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089083/pure-virtual-function-with-implementation)

I have a base class which has a function called `time()`.
My idea is to have a pure virtual function which all the classes that inherits from it must implement.

However I also want to add the default behavior; Whoever calls `time()` function needs to print "hello".

Is that possible?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089083/pure-virtual-function-with-implementation

Comment: I don't think the Q being marked as duplicate answers this Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve something like this would be to have something like the following:

```
  class base {
       virtual void time_impl()=0;
  public:
       void time() {
             //Default behaviour
             std::cout << "Hello\n";
             //Call overridden behaviour
             time_impl();
       }
  };

  class child : public base {
       void time_impl() override {
            //Functionality
       }
  };
```

This way, when any child's `time` function is called, it calls the base classes time function, which does the default behaviour, and then make the `virtual` call to the overridden behaviour.

### EDIT:

As Als says in the comments, this is called the Template method pattern which you  can read about here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Althought for C++ that is a rather confusing name (as templates are something else, and "methods" don't mean anything in C++ (rather `member function`).

### EDIT:

Someone commented about the use of override, this is a C++11 feature, if you have it USE IT, it will save many headaches in the long run:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicit_overrides_and_final

And also, the `_impl` function should be private, UNLESS you want the user to be to bypass the default behaviour, but I would argue that's a poor design in most use-cases.

### Working test case

http://ideone.com/eZBpyX

Comment: You might as well add, this is the famous Template method design pattern.

Comment: +1 for C++11 - I forgot `override` was in there. Edit: nevermind the second question, thanks for making me learn something new!

Comment: Worth noting, that this forces the child to implement both `time` and `time_impl`.

Comment: @icepack why does the child have to implement time?

Comment: @111111 Because this is the requirement and the defined interface

Comment: @icepack the child will inherit `time` from it's parent and meet whatever interface requirements there are, it works as expected here: http://ideone.com/eZBpyX

Comment: @111111 I'm not talking about technicalities, I'm talking about the interface as defined by OP. Your solution, while forcing the default behavior, also requires the child to implement `time_impl` - this is a somewhat break of encapsulation since it dictates the child details of its private implementation.

Comment: @icepack I think we might differ on what's we consider good design, but I don't consider `private` to only encapsulate the inner workings of the class itself, using it to encapsulate the inner workings of a system like this if fine IMO. (That said, I personally would probably favour a template approach if I could at all get away with it).

Comment: Such things are usually not something that can be played with freely. In a usual scenario you provide an interface (`time` here) and the client implements it in a way he feels right. Forcing the client to implement additional stuff to make the system work contradicts the concept of `interface`.

Comment: @Als I think in this context it's more important to mention the http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the default behavior in your base class by making your `virtual` function not `pure virtual`.
However, you can't force the implementation to invoke this default behavior without posing some restrictions on child's implementation (see @111111 answer for details). You should inspect you requirements to see if this is an acceptable solution.