# Implementing a class hierarchy properly

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, interface, implementation

Say I have an interface hierarchy :

```
class A
{
   virtual void commonFunc() = 0;
};

class B1 : public A
{
   virtual void b1SpecificFunc() = 0;
};

class B2 : public A
{
   virtual void b2SpecificFunc() = 0;
};
```

Interface A only exist to avoid duplicating the commonFunc() function.

Now if I want to implement this in order to have 2 instanciatable classes ImplB1 and ImplB2 i could do :

```
class ImplA
{
   virtual void commonFunc();
};

class ImplB1 : public ImplA
{
   virtual void b1SpecificFunc();
};

class ImplB2 : public ImplA
{
   virtual void b2SpecificFunc();
};
```

The problem with this is that it makes ImplA instanciatable, which I don't want to. I only want ImplB1 and ImplB2 to be instanciatable, because ImplA is something asbtract that only exist to have the implementation of the common function in common.

How could i design this please ? Thank you.

Comment: Make ImplA's constructors protected and / or don't inherit from ImplA and use composition to share commonFunc's implementation.

Comment: @KristianDuske: Or just take `commonFunc` out of the entire class hierarchy. It's difficult to say without knowing more details.

Comment: Composition +1. Why not make constructors private but friends to Bs and instantiate it as a mebmer in Bs?

Answer (score 2):

> Interface A only exist to avoid duplicating the commonFunc() function.

You certainly mean to avoid duplicating its *declaration*, don't you?

> ```
> class ImplA
> {
>    virtual void commonFunc();
> };
> ```

This should probably be:

```
class ImplA : public A
{
   virtual void commonFunc();
};
```

And I guess the point is that `ImplA` actually has an implementation of `commonFunc`. So for the sake of this answer's brevity, let's put it into the class definition:

```
class ImplA : public A
{
   virtual void commonFunc() {} // implementation
};
```

> The problem with this is that it makes ImplA instanciatable.

Just make `ImplA`'s destructor pure virtual:

```
class ImplA : public A
{
public:
   virtual ~ImplA() = 0 {}

private:
   virtual void commonFunc() {}
};
```

This will prevent instantiation even inside of derived classes' functions. For example, the following will create a compiler error:

```
class ImplB1 : public ImplA
{
public:
   virtual void b1SpecificFunc()
   {
       ImplA a; // error, cannot instantiate abstract class
   }
};
```

In fact, you will not even be able to instantiate the class in its own functions:

```
class ImplA : public A
{
public:
   virtual ~ImplA() = 0 {}

private:
   virtual void commonFunc()
   {
       ImplA a; // error, cannot instantiate abstract class
   }
};
```

But seriously, this all seems pretty **over-engineered**. Perhaps what you really need is to make `commonFunc` a non-virtual protected function of `A`, which derived classes can then call if they need to.

Or perhaps `commonFunc` can just be a **free-standing utility function**?

Comment: virtual ~ImplA() = 0 {} what sorcery is this?!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yeah it might seem a bit over complicated, but alll the solutions i thought about had something dirty. I'm not sure what you mean by free-standing utility functions, but this function is actually several functions common to both subclasses.

Comment: @KristianDuske: Well, it's a pure virtual destructor with an implementation. The destructor needs an implementation. At the end of the day, `= 0` really just means "the class of this member function is abstract", not "this function cannot be implemented".

Comment: @Virus721: It depends on what this `commonFunc` actually does. In C++, you don't have to put every function into a class. It's often easier (and *better* for a cleaner OOP approach!) to make functions completely free-standing.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I wasn't aware that this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following. Also, here is a SO [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089083/pure-virtual-function-with-implementation) about this.

**Note:** While I'm answering the question that you *can do  this* I'm not asserting it's what you *should do*.

### Code

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void commonFunc() = 0;
};


void A::commonFunc() // Pure virtual but implemented anyway
{
    // Derived classes can explicitly opt-in to this implementation
    std::cout << "A::commonFunc()\n";
}

class B1 : public A
{
public:
    virtual void b1SpecificFunc() = 0;
};

class B2 : public A
{
    virtual void b2SpecificFunc() = 0;
};

class ImplB1 : public B1
{
public:
    // This function must be implemented because its declared pure virtual
    virtual void commonFunc()
    {
        // Can override the behavior if desired...
        A::commonFunc(); // Explicitly use default implementation
    }

    virtual void b1SpecificFunc()
    {
        std::cout << "b1SpecificFunc()\n";
    }
};

class ImplB2 : public B2
{
public:
    // This function must be implemented because its declared pure virtual
    virtual void commonFunc()
    {
        // Can override the behavior if desired...
        A::commonFunc(); // Explicitly use default implementation
    }

    virtual void b2SpecificFunc()
    {
        std::cout << "b2SpecificFunc()\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    //A a; // Won't compile (as expected/desired)
    ImplB1 b1;
    ImplB2 b2;

    b1.commonFunc();
    b1.b1SpecificFunc();

    b2.commonFunc();
    b2.b2SpecificFunc();

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
A::commonFunc()
b1SpecificFunc()
A::commonFunc()
b2SpecificFunc()
```