# Do derived classes need their own version of a virtual function declared on base?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

For instance, the class `Plant` has a `virtual void info()` method. The class `flower` derives from `Plant`.
Is `Plant` obligated to have its own implementation of the method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pure virtual function with implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089083/pure-virtual-function-with-implementation)

Comment: Are you asking whether your compiler is standards compliant in accepting your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function is [*pure virtual*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class), that is declared `virtual void info() = 0;`, then No. Otherwise Yes.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Base classes do not *need* their own implementation of a virtual method that is implemented by a dervided class. However, they *can* have an implementation.

To skip the implementation in the base class, just make it pure virtual, e.g.

```
virtual void info() = 0;
```

In that case any derived classes - or to be more specific: any derived class that you want to have an instance of - needs to implement the virtual method.

Comment: But the question is the other way around, I'm afraid. I was talking about declaring the virtual function on the base class and not on the derived one.