# Casting function returns to void

Tags: c

Many times I see in open source code that a call to a C function is cast to void.

For example, in the source code for `ls` (http://cvs.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/cmd/ls/ls.c) I see the following.

```
(void) setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

Why is this good practice?

Comment: For C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689677/casting-unused-return-values-to-void

Comment: add another link for further reference: https://c-faq.com/style/voidcasts.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It explicitly means you ignore the return value, and did not just forget it.

Comment: Some static analyzers warn if a return value is silently ignored and don't warn when you explicitly ignore by casting to void. It was more important when we had only error codes and no exceptions ...

Comment: @Peter G.:  This question is tagged C.  They still don't have exceptions.

Comment: @David good point! :) Then let's forget about the second sentence of my first commend.

Comment: Its a way to hide the fact for the static analyzer that you are ignoring that error code that you should have checked; and that in three years some poor slub will have to debug a problem caused by the fact that you did not check the error code.