# why (void) is used while invoking function?

Tags: c, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [casting unused return values to void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689677/casting-unused-return-values-to-void)
>   [Need for prefixing a function with (void)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035927/need-for-prefixing-a-function-with-void)
>   [Casting function returns to void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998802/casting-function-returns-to-void)

Have seen in quite few places that while invoking the function why do we explicitly the return type of the function ? ex:

```
(void) myhostnames ( char * something);
```

What is use of this (void), and how it differs from not using the same ? 
Kindly clarify.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689677/casting-unused-return-values-to-void

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the function returns something and to prevent warnings from the compiler / errors from lint, the caller explicitly "throws" away the return.

Comment: It's a way of the programmer saying to anyone who reviews this code (whether human or machine), "I know that this function returns a value and in this case the right thing to do is ignore that value. I'm calling this function for some reason other than to get its return value."