# C++ What is the purpose of casting to void?

Tags: c++, virtual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [casting unused return values to void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689677/casting-unused-return-values-to-void)

I read some source code, and in it many virtual functions in the interface classes are declared and default-implemented as such:

```
virtual bool FunctionName(TypeName* pointer)
{
   (void)pointer;
   return true;
}
```

May I ask what is the purpose of casting the pointer to void in the default implementation?

Comment: This should not compile, as the function needs to return a value.

Comment: That was asked around numerous times. Casting something to `void` indicates you're not using the return value. In your case, it's a no-op.

Comment: @zneak: `pointer` isn't a return value. Not a dupe of that question, although I'm sure this has been covered before for parameters too.

Comment: What I don't understand here is why the code isn't just `FunctionName(TypeName*) { }` (maybe with a return value). What compiler would spit out an "unused" warning for that?

Comment: @Steve that's an virtual function with an inline definition, so if it's a base class which has do-nothing definitions, then you still want the names of the arguments for documentation purposes.

Comment: @Steve Jessop The expression `pointer;` alone returns the value of `pointer`. Casting that to void ignores the return value of the expression, and as such does nothing. The cast behaves the same as if you casted the return value of a function (minus the effects of the function itself, obviously).

Comment: @zneak: expressions don't have return values, they have results. I think that the reasons you would cast a return value to void are different from the reasons that you would write a statement just for the purpose of casting a parameter to void. One is normally for the attention of developers (to show that you're deliberately ignoring a possible error), the other is normally for the attention of the compiler (to suppress a warning). Only one of the answers to that other question has anything to do with this one, and that's the one mentioning lint. Still, you've won the vote, so fair enough.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Multiple purposes depending on what you cast

- Marking your intention to the compiler that an expression that is entirely a no-op is intended as written (for inhibiting warnings, for example)
- Marking your intention to to the compiler and programmer that the result of something is ignored (the result of a function call, for example)
- In a function template, if a return type is given by a template parameter type `T`, and you return the result of some function call that could be different from `T` in some situation. An explicit cast to `T` could, in the `void` case, prevent a compile time error:
      `int f() { return 0; } void g() { return (void)f(); }`
- Inhibiting the compiler to choose a comma operator overload (`(void)a, b` will never invoke an overloaded comma operator function).

Note that the Standard guarantees that there will never be an `operator void()` called if you cast a class object to `void` (some GCC versions ignore that rule, though).

Answer (score 13):

In this case it's just to avoid compiler's warning about unused parameter.

Comment: +1: for giving the correct answer

Comment: Why make such a parameter in the first place?

Comment: The parameter could occur because some other class that also implements this virtual function actually does use that parameter.

Comment: Example: In one of your subclasses, you expect a parameter x of a virtual function to be always zero. You write an assert (x == 0) but don't use x otherwise. (void) x has a good chance of compiling an a debug and a release version without warnings.