# What does `(void)varName;` do?

Tags: c++, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [casting unused return values to void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689677/casting-unused-return-values-to-void)
>   [C++ What is the purpose of casting to void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178695/c-what-is-the-purpose-of-casting-to-void)

After downloading and building the [GDCM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gdcm/) code using CMake, I stumbled upon this:

```
void error_callback(const char *msg, void *) {
    (void)msg;
    gdcmErrorMacro( "Error in gdcmopenjpeg" << msg );
}
```

What does the first line do? Never seen something like that. Keep in mind that I told CMake to build using Visual Studio 2010, if that matters.

Comment: Please be more specific in the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It prevents *unused variable* warnings. Presumably the macro `gdcmErrorMacro()` can be `#define`d as an empty macro and `msg` would not be referenced in that case.

Answer (score 3):

This prevents a compiler warning emitted when a function's formal parameters aren't used in the function.

It is a generally good idea to compile production code with warnings treated as errors, so this looks like an attempt to clear that up before `msg` was referred to in the macro use.

This could also have been taken care of by simply not naming a formal parameter in the first place -- in fact, that's what I'd do IRL if there is no mention of `msg` when using the macro:

```
void error_callback(const char *, void *) {
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this fail to compile when `msg` is needed by the macro?

Comment: But you need to name the parameter in order to use it in the macro argument, if the macro is defined to do something with it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour & dario_ramos: Right.  Edited.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `msg` is not used by that function and the compiler will complain (warning) about unused parameters.

The `(void)msg;` line simply "uses" that parameter (with no effect). This way, the compiler does not generate the warning.

edit: actually, the function uses that parameter, but the macro `gdcmErrorMacro` could be set (through a compile-defined macro) to expand to... nothing (for example, to an empty `do{}while(0);` construction, as customary in the Linux kernel.

This way, the compiler will see nothing in the body of the function that makes use of the parameter `msg` (remember that the compiler sees the *preprocessed* source file, so the macros are already expanded).

In that case, after preprocessing, the compiler will see:

```
void error_callback(const char *msg, void *) {
    (void)msg;
    do{ }while(0);
}
```

and the sole "use" of the parameter `msg` would be that line `(void)msg;`.