# statement in boost lib, (void)p; what does it mean?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I came across following piece of code in Boost Library for offset_ptr. under boost/interprocess/offset_ptr.hpp

```
typedef PointedType *                     pointer;
...
    //!Constructor from other pointer.
    //!Never throws.
    template <class T>
    offset_ptr(T *ptr) 
    {  pointer p (ptr);  (void)p; this->set_offset(p); }
```

I wonder what does a statement (void)p; does?

Comment: Indent code by 4 spaces, or press the `{}` button, so that SO displays it in fixed-width and highlights it. Someone with 284 reputation ought to know that by now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [casting unused return values to void](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689677/casting-unused-return-values-to-void)

Comment: Perhaps this is triggering some side-effect inside a typecast operator?

Comment: Normaly such code is used to silence unused parameter/variable warnings, but this doesn't seem to be the case here. Strange

Comment: @Chris: `p` is not a return value, so this isn't a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Skizz: Nope. `pointer` is a `PointedType *`, which means the conversion to `void` is a built-in, without side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to find out is to put a break point on that line of code and step through to find out what it does. You can even reformat the code to allow you to set the break point on that particular statement (there's no law against editing these files - just don't change the actual code).

However, my guess is that the `pointer` type is using some form of lazy evaluation, the emulated cast operators call a `set_offset` method so maybe the `this->set_offset(p)` requires `p` to have a valid offset set up and doing the `(void)p` just forces it to happen.

Comment: I have tried setting break point see if there is any change in value also tried removing it. It does not make any difference. When you said "p to have a valid offset set up and doing the (void)p", does it mean something like an assert?

Comment: @Rahul: no, not like an assert, more like ensuring a precondition is fulfilled.

Comment: So what happens if it is not full filled?

Comment: @Rahul: If the value is not set up, `this->set_offset(p)` would probably fail in some undefined way.