# Determine the largest number among three numbers using C++

Tags: c++

How can I determine the largest number among three numbers using C++?

I need to simplify this

```
 w=(z>((x>y)?x:y)?z:((x>y)?x:y));
```

Conditionals do not simplify this.

Comment: Define "simplify". If it's a code golf problem you should post it here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find maximum of three number in C without using conditional statement and ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074010/find-maximum-of-three-number-in-c-without-using-conditional-statement-and-ternar)

Comment: `(x > y) ? (x > z ? x : z) : (y > z ? y : z);` is better ordering of the brackets..  There is also `std::max_element(std::begin(array), std::end(array))` which would give you the position in the array of the maximum element.

Comment: @NehaGupta Not a dupe; that question is for C

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Starting from C++11, you can do

```
w = std::max({ x, y, z });
```

Comment: @Bathsheba - But (and it's a big one) yours preforms no copies. This one I'd wager copies all the elements (though I won't encourage anyone to optimize prematurely based on this).

Comment: @StoryTeller: Careful: I've already upvoted 2 answers of yours today.

Comment: I guess! Stackoverflow is turning to trading reputation website! :D

Comment: @StoryTeller That argument works both ways. In the two-argument version of `std::max`, arguments are passed by references. For built-in numeric types or small POD types, passing the value is usually cheaper than passing a reference and dereferencing the references in the function itself. In practice, it will probably all be inlined. But yes, good point, this is something worth considering.

Comment: @NehaGupta - Hardly. Bathsheba and I just happen to frequent the same tags, and engage in friendly banter.

Comment: @oisyn - Of course, no disrespect to your answer. I can't really choose between the two myself :)

Comment: Here is the solution I found: `w = ((y > z) || (x > z)) ? ((x > y) ? x: y) :z;`. It is utilizes less operations and very transparent.

Comment: I think they should've made a C++11 style varags version of `::std::max`.

Answer (score 8):

```
w = std::max(std::max(x, y), z);
```

is one way.

Comment: I think he's trying to use conditional operator.

Comment: @NehaGupta then the OP should add that to their question =)

Comment: @NehaGupta: Why?

Answer (score 2):

big = a > b ? (a > c ? a : c) : (b > c ? b : c) ;

Comment: @YSC may i know why?

Comment: Would you trust it in a missile guidance system?

Comment: Would you dare maintain it *if it was* in a missile guidance system?

Comment: @Bathsheba not the best example: I'd say the world would be a better place if guidance missile engineers wrote that kind of software...

Comment: Readability goes along way.

Comment: @YSC - In my part of the world, those missiles intercept enemy missiles. Won't be better for us if engineers wrote this kind of code.

Comment: @YSC: Sometimes we do: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/patriot.html

Comment: @Bathsheba why that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple `if` condition

```
int w = x;

if(y > w)
  w = y;
if(z > w)
  w = z;
```

Where `w` is the max among three.

Answer (score 0):

A variant on [oisyn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47414569/27678) (use an initializer list) and [Bathesheba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47414493/27678) (invoke no copies) is to use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to create an initializer list of references, and then use `std::max` normally:

```
using std::ref;
w = std::max({ref(x), ref(y), ref(z)});
```

This is only advantageous if creating a reference is cheaper than creating a copy (and it isn't for primitives like `int`)

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/itgt4bqCsBBIYMJG)

Comment: Do we really want to leave this open to ADL?

Comment: @StoryTeller: I thought it cleaner than passing my own lambda for comparison.

Comment: I mean `ref`. We explicitly want the result of `std::ref`. If the user type defines a `ref` function the does something else entirely, this will break.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Indeed. Probably unlikely IMO. My personal style is to always qualify the standard namespace; here I added a `using` for readability. It's certainly something every programmer needs to keep in mind when using ADL.