# void cast of argc and argv

Tags: c++

I'm looking at a piece of C++ code, and the first line in the main function caught my attention:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    (void)argc; (void)argv;
     ...
}
```

Apart from this line argc and argv aren't used at all. Why is the author doing a void cast? Could it be to stop the compiler from complaining about unused variables?

Comment: Although in this case the author should have just used `int main()`. Compiler warning problem solved!

Comment: Note that main is not required to take those arguments, so if you don't use them, just leave them out. Also, at least VC++2005 does not warn if the arguments have no name (in case you need to preserve the signature for some reason).

Comment: This could be because of some idea for some future use of the parameters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [casting unused return values to void](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689677/casting-unused-return-values-to-void)

Comment: @Nawaz: it's certainly a duplicate, but not of the question that you link to, which is about (void) casts of return values.

Comment: @PaulR: The answer is there. The function call is an expression, so are variables. Conceptually, there is no difference between `(void)e1()` and `(void)e2`, as in both `e1()` and `e2` are expressions, even though `e1()` is a function call, and `e2` is just a variable.

Comment: @Nawaz: the difference though is that unused function arguments (or variables) typically generating a warning, whereas an unused function result typically does not

Comment: @PaulR: that depends on compiler and the compiler-options.

Answer (score 20):

"Could it be to stop the compiler from complaining about unused variables?"

yes

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's exactly to tell the compiler not to complain about unused variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `-Werror` option, the compiler makes all warnings into errors, stopping compilation. It's a good practice set `-Wall -Werror` to check all inconsistences.

Comment: I think that `-Wall` (perhaps with `-Wextra`) is good practice, but I am less positive about `-Werror`. There are very rare cases where a specific warning given by `-Wall` should be skipped (but then, you should explain in a big comment why is it so).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is to prevent the compiler from complaining about unused variables. In this case a better way would be:

```
int main(int, char**) {
    ...
}
```

Leaving the parameters unnamed tells the compiler that they're there but are not used.