# What does void casting do?

Tags: c, casting, void

I was reading some source code, and this came up;

```
struct Cookie *
Curl_cookie_add(struct SessionHandle *data, /* rest of params were here */)
{
/* unrelated things were here */
#ifdef CURL_DISABLE_VERBOSE_STRINGS
  (void)data;
#endif
/* rest of function goes here */
}
```

As you can see, void casted pointer, isn't even assigned to a variable. I was wondering what is the purpose of this.

Comment: Is this a raw copy-pasta? is it possible that its casted to a `void *`, not void?

Comment: possible duplicate of [casting unused return values to void](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689677/casting-unused-return-values-to-void)

Comment: Please search the existing questions and answers before posting.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII yes, this is raw copy paste; check this out: https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/lib/cookie.c#L198

Comment: @AdamLiss nope, not a dupe. this is about a struct, not a function.

Comment: Not true.  In both cases an unused value is cast to `void` to avoid a compiler warning.  This one happens to be a pointer to a structure, but it's still an unused function argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cast suppresses a compiler warning that would arise if `data` is not used.

GCC produces this warning if the `-Wunused-parameter` flag (implied by `-Wextra`) is enabled.

Comment: What compiler/flags would be needed for that warning? With GCC, I have no issues w/ that.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: It appears with `-Wall -W`, but I'm still looking for the exact flag.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question *Why* - it gives a method of hiding the problem?  I suggest that suppressing warnings is not an ideal solution.

Comment: @Andrew: This is selective suppression of a warning, so the coder can indicate that a particular function purposely does not use a particular parameter.  When you don't use a variable, it's often a mistake or unfinished code, except in some cases (e.g. a callback function where parameters are provided in case you need them).  So we want unused warnings except in those special cases.

Answer (score 0):

Fair point Joey - but suppressing that warning also suppresses it for all the cases where the programmer has accidentally not used a parameter...