# Why does a void pointer point to anything?

Tags: c

When something is cast to void, then the value becomes `NULL`. However, why does a `void *` point to any data type? Shouldn't a void pointer just be useless?

Comment: *When something is cast to void, then the value becomes NULL.* Needs proof/citation ;-)

Comment: A `void` pointer is far from useless. Unlike the "typed" pointers, it lets the programmer legitimately decide what it points to. However, the legitimacy of that is, of course, totally up to the programmer.

Comment: casts to not change values, just how they are interpreted in that context... it can invoke an instruction on the value of the variable to change it to a double, for instance but the original value will not be changed.

Comment: @BlueMoon I guess there is confusion between `void` and `void*` here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689677/casting-unused-return-values-to-void

It says that casting to <code>void</code> will throw the value out

Comment: @EdwardKarak I see you still don't know the difference between `void` and `void *`. `void` is the lack of a variable type. When used with a function, it indicates that the function has no variable type (and therefore does not return any information). When used with a pointer, it indicates that the pointer has no variable type (and therefore does not know *what type of variable is in the memory address it points to*). The difference is substantial.

Comment: "*why does a void\* point to any data type*" it actually does **not**, and that is what makes it special.

Comment: "*When something is cast to `void` ...*" you probably wanted to write "*When something is cast to `void *` ...*".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A void pointer is a pointer to anything.  It is a generic pointer that doesn't have a particular type.  It can also have the value `NULL` in which case it doesn't point to anything.
To use a void pointer, you have to keep track of what it actually points to and when you are going to use it, you must cast it to the appropriate type.

They can be dangerous, because if you cast it to the wrong type, it will result in undefined behavior at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

> When something is cast to void, then the value becomes NULL.

Not true. Nothing happens to the pointed data.

> Shouldn't a void pointer just be useless?

A void pointer is the closest thing C has to a "generic type" and is very useful in that it allows things like somewhat generic functions, somewhat generic containers etc.

Answer (score 2):

`void *` is a generic object pointer. Note that there is no generic function pointer.

You can convert any object pointer value to `void *` and back without loss of value.