# Is casting a function return to void an "old-style-cast" or not?

Tags: c++, casting, suppress-warnings

Coverity has complained that various function calls in our codebase are not checking the return value.

> Unchecked return value (CHECKED_RETURN)3. check_return: Calling Append
>   without checking return value (as is done elsewhere 73 out of 78
>   times).

In the past, we would have simply resolved this issue (after double-checking that the return value really was not important) by casting the return to `void` (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689677/why-cast-unused-return-values-to-void)):

```
(void)Foo.Append(bar);
```

However, we are moving towards enabling all warnings, *and* treating warnings as errors, so I'm a little concerned that the above code will generate an `old-style-cast` diagnostic. If that's the case, I will need to modify our code to the considerably uglier format:

```
static_cast<void>( Foo.Append(bar) );
```

However, both **gcc** and **clang** seem to be able to compile this code (the *first* form) without complaining. So I suppose the final form of my question is this: Is casting a function return to `void` considered an exception to the rule as far as C-style casts are concerned? Or do I need to double check my code and see if the lines in question aren't actually being included in those builds?

Comment: The MSVC compiler emits an analyzer warning for the `(void)` cast because it is a "C style cast". I don't get that warning when using `static_cast`.

Comment: Tangential: You could `#define IGNORE_RET(func) static_cast<void>(func)` and then have `IGNORE_RET(Foo.Append(bar));` to self document that you are intentionally ignoring the return.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was considering something like that. We do have a macro called UNUSED but its primary use is unused function parameters, and I was concerned that if I used that, some future "optimization" would improve it so it didn't evaluate its parameter... so I shied away from it. A more clearly named macro, as you suggest, might be the best solution

Comment: @WernerHenze Thank you for the information. Which version of MSVC are you using? I didn't see this warning

Comment: Does anyone else have issues with the fact that you're ignoring a return value specifically marked to not be ignored? Either the marking is erronous (get rid of it then!) or you really should not ignore it.

Comment: @rubenvb usually when we append an item to a vector, we check the return value to see if we ran out of memory. Sometimes, though, we resize the vector to pre-allocate enough items to hold everything we're going to add, then iterate through without checking for failure in every individual case.

Comment: @TimRandall I just tested again to confirm and saw the warning using VS15.9.2. As this is a code analysis warning it is not sufficient to just compile the code, you also have to enable code analysis and set the rule set to "Microsoft All Rules".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's fine.

```
(void) f(x);
```

is always equivalent to a `static_cast` as per [`[expr.static.cast]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#6):

> Any expression can be explicitly converted to type cv void, in which case it becomes a discarded-value expression.

Converting the result of a function to `void` is *the* way to make an expression a [*discard-value-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prop#def:discarded-value_expression). Now, the C++ way should be `static_cast<void>(...)`but `(void) ...` is an idiom (and is shorter).

Since the latter is well-defined and really common in codebases, gcc<sup>1</sup> and clang<sup>2</sup> made it *not* trigger `Wold-style-cast`.

It's well-defined, recognized by major compilers. It's fine.

---

<sup>1)</sup> [g++ documentation --- 3.5 Options Controlling C++ Dialect](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html)

> `-Wold-style-cast` (C++ and Objective-C++ only)
>   Warn if an old-style (C-style) **cast to a non-void** type is used within a C++ program. The new-style casts (`dynamic_cast`, `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, and `const_cast`) are less vulnerable to unintended effects and much easier to search for.

<sup>2)</sup> [not documented](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wold-style-cast)