# Is it right to use static_cast<void> to ignore iterator as return value?

Tags: c++, c++17, compiler-warnings, nodiscard

I have to handle the [[nodiscard]] warning from `std::remove`;

```
static_cast<void>(std::remove(stringVar.begin(), stringVar.end(), ' '));
```

I want the correct way to do it. The warning can be stopped by below code:

```
auto temp = std::remove(stringVar.begin(), stringVar.end(), ' ');
```

**I dont want to use the return value of `std::remove`.**

```
void main()
{
    std::string stringVar { "Operation : In , Value : 3884 ," };

    size_t from = 0, to = 0, pos = 0;
    std::string delFrom{ ":" }, delTo{ "," };

    static_cast<void>(std::remove(stringVar.begin(), stringVar.end(), ' '));

    from = stringVar.find(delFrom, pos);
    to = stringVar.find(delTo, pos);
    std::cout<< stringVar.substr(from + 1, to - from - 1);
}
```

Output:

```
In
```

This is a specific question do not interested in already searched question on SO.

Update: Data consistent and readable format.

Comment: The problem here is that if you don't use `temp` you haven't properly removed the spaces from your string.

Comment: If you're getting a warning about discarding a return value, that supposed to be interpreted as a sign that your code has problems, *not* that you should find a way to silence the warning.

Comment: @john I am doing search again on stringVar for first occurrence delimiter. So, I am not interested in garbage pointed by return iterator

Comment: This is something like "the check engine light of my car is on, how do I remove the bulb?"

Comment: What are you trying to archive? Remove is designed to work with erase. You should probably use another algorithm for what you want. We can help you find it.

Comment: @JHBonarius example is updated

Comment: Note that with input such as `"         "`, output is allowed to be "hello". `std::partition` seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that if you don't use `temp` you haven't properly removed the spaces from your string.

The correct code is

```
auto temp = std::remove(stringVar.begin(), stringVar.end(), ' ')
stringVar.erase(temp, stringVar.end());
```

You see `std::remove` does not remove anything from anything (how can it when all it has are two iterators?). All it does is rearrange the string so that the items at the end of the string are the part of the string that should be erased (you can think of it as moving all the spaces to the end of the string but actually it's more complicated than that).

To actually erase you need to call `string::erase`, using the iterator returned by `std::remove` as the code above shows.

Comment: I dont want to use erase-remove idiom. I am not interested in return value.

Comment: @BuildSucceeded To confirm, you want the "removed" elements to hang around at the end of the container?

Comment: @BuildSucceeded Using `std::remove` for a purpose other than removing items is such a strange thing that perhaps you should have made that clear in the question. Otherwise almost everyone is going to assume that you are just a beginner making a beginners mistake. So you are just interested in the rearrangement that `std::remove` performs? For what reason?

Comment: @user4581301 I am fine with those, as I am going for some search which does not go to those

Comment: sorry @john or confusing question, but I stressed on handling warning. I will improve question

Comment: Accepted the Answer as it is the correct way to keep the data and code in understandable format

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @john, the operation won't work if you discard the value. That is the whole point of the `[[nodiscard]]` specifier which is to *prevent* the user from ignoring its value.

---

If you have a good reason to ignore the warning, the method you already suggest is the best way to do this. Which is to cast it to `void`.

```cpp
static_cast < void >
```

If you wanna use a macro

```
#define ignore(x) (static_cast < void > (x))
```

Read more: [**How can I intentionally discard a no-discard return value?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53581744/how-can-i-intentionally-discard-a-nodiscard-return-value)