# Exclude a function's return value from [[nodiscard]]

Tags: c++, c++17, nodiscard

I want to mark a class as nodiscard, but exclude the return value of a certain function from the nodiscard requirement. This is my goal:

```
enum class [[nodiscard]] Result {
  OK1,
  OK2,
  ERROR,
};

[[ok-to-discard]] // This attribute is made up to illustrate my need.
Result doSomethingThatCannotFail() {
  // The function can return OK1 or OK2, but the caller may or may not care.
  // The function cannot return ERROR.
  // Therefore, it's OK to discard this particular Result return value,
  // even though in general Result should not be ignored.
}
```

I do not believe it's a good idea to add ok-to-discard at every call site (which is covered by
[How can I intentionally discard a [[nodiscard]] return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53581744/how-can-i-intentionally-discard-a-nodiscard-return-value)):

- There are many callsites. It would be nice to avoid adding ok-to-discard everywhere.
- Maybe one day I'll change the function, and it will no longer be OK to discard. It would be preferable to keep the ok-to-discard instruction with the function so that I can drop it when that happens (and get compiler warnings/errors).

Comment: And why don't you want to add `[[nodiscard]]` to every function? Seems to be as troublesome as what you are doing right now.
PS: I realized that you probably think that `[[nodiscard]]` is only for types...It is not.

Comment: So out of curiosity, when is "OK" not exactly OK but still OK?

Comment: Have two different enums?  A `[[nodiscard]] FailableResult` and a plain `NonFailableResult`?

Comment: It's just a warning so I would ignore and put a comment. Or you can use compiler pragmas to hid it, like `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored <warning_to_ignore>`.You should not declare the class as `[[nodiscard]]` if it is valid to discard it in some instances.

Comment: A somewhat terrible solution: `Result` is `[[nodiscard]]`, but `const Result&` isn't, so you can return references to `static constexpr` variables defined in the function instead.

Comment: Perhaps make a wrapper function that perfectly-forward the values and explicitly discard the result for every such function (or just template-wrap them)?