# Why compile give note in std::initializer_list regarding function template specialization?

Tags: c++, std, compiler-warnings

I wrote a `printf` function using `std::initializer_list`:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
auto printf(T t, Ts... args) {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
    return std::initializer_list<T>{([&] {
        std::cout << args << std::endl;
    }(), t)...};
}

int main() {
    printf(111, 123, "alpha", 1.2);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives a note on instantiation of function template specialization:

```
warning: returning address of local temporary object [-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return std::initializer_list<T>{([&] {
                                   ^~~~~~~
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'printf<int, int, const char *, double>' requested here
    printf(111, 123, "alpha", 1.2);
```

I aware of returning stack address is a bad practice, however, if I don't do return then I will receive:

```
warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
```

How could I change my code to avoid these three type of compiler warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I change my code to avoid these three type of compiler warnings?

Don't return the object and use the good old `(void)`-trick (see e.g. [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689677/why-cast-unused-return-values-to-void/689716) for more info on that):

```
(void) std::initializer_list<T>{ /* ... */ };
```

By the way, pretty awesome `printf` implementation :)

Answer (score 2):

Cast initializer_list to void to show the compiler you do not use it intentionally